# publishing to svn from perforce?

Tags: svn, perforce

I have two projects which I manage internally using Perforce.  These are also published to google code using svn.

> http://code.google.com/p/orapig/
>
> http://code.google.com/p/cx-oracle-demos/

I currently have a set of scripts that copy from the perforce area in my home directory to the svn area, sync it, diff it, and commit it.

It seems that I might be able to just do a svn checkout in the perforce-managed area and perform the svn operations in place.

Has anybody done something like that?  Any hints, pointers, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not, if you can make perforce ignore the .svn directories, then a SVN WC is just an ordinary directory of files.

You can make your changes to those files, and commit them as normal using SVN - SVN simply uses the .svn dirs to detect whether anything has changed and to generate the diffs to send to the repository. Perforce won't affect any part of that - as long as you can make it ignore the .svn dirs.